# Starring a chat message through dropdown while suspended says it is starred, when it's not

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension, chat-stars, chat-transcript

While under a chat suspension, clicking on the star to star a message results in a notification saying that a user cannot vote while suspended.

But while attempting to star via the dropdown, it says the starring was successful.

> You have starred and pinned this message.

Refreshing the page shows otherwise (it wasn't actually starred).

[image]

Comment: That's because how transcript works (I can see it's the transcript because of a "history" link without edit count). I can also find myself able to "unstar" messages I have starred some 5m ago, and then, if I refresh, the message is still starred, despite my "unstarring". The transcript isn't live, but I think it *can* be enhanced by *not* making users think they have done something they really haven't.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The difference is that if I star something using a message's dropdown in the transcript, it *will* actually be starred upon refreshing. But you are right. It's not live, but it should be improved to be less misleading. A notification if the action cannot be performed, rather than a silent failure, would be useful.

Comment: I think that's different from what you've mentioned. `Refreshing the page shows otherwise (it wasn't actually starred).`

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I was under a chat suspension at the time. (see the question description). This might also occur if it's not a transcript, but I can't test it anymore, since I'm no longer suspended.